# Remove all hyperlinks and tables from RTF using c#

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox, rtf

I have a Winform RichTextBox to which I am programatically loading RTF documents. But I want to strip/remove all hyperlinks and tables from the RTF before loading the RTF into the RichTextBox ( but needs to keep the formatting). Same behavior I need for RTF texts copied from MS Word also.
How do I achive this? Are there any library to parse the RTF and strip hyperlinks and tables (still keeping the formatting) ?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to check their rtf format and remove them with regular expressions.

**Edit:**
For example, you can use something like this for hyperlinks:

```
Regex rHyperlink = new Regex(@"{\\field{\\\*\\fldinst{HYPERLINK [^}]+}}{\\fldrslt{(?:\\cf\d+)?(?:\\ul)?([^}]+)}}}");
richTextBox1.Rtf = rHyperlink.Replace(richTextBox1.Rtf, "$1");
```